# como usar websockets?

Tags: php, javascript, html5, websocket

por favor nesecito de su ayuda estoy creando una app y quiero mandar datos por websockets pero no se como recibir los datos ya que cree una pagina para enviar ejemplo: pagEnvia.html y quiero recibir los datos en mi index.php tengo este codigo que consegui en internet pero no entiendo el recibimiento de mensaje.

como lo hago?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var ws;

      function initSocket(){

          ws = new WebSocket("wss://echo.websocket.org");
          ws.onopen = function(event){
            alert('Conexion Abierta');
            //ws.send('{"setID":"Realbingo90","passwd":"12345"}');
            setInterval(function(){
              ws.send("hola mundo");
            }, 1000);
          }

          ws.onmessage = function(event){
            console.log(event.data);
          }

          ws.onclose= function(){
             alert('Cerrado');
          }
      }

    initSocket();
```

nesesito de su pronta ayuda.

Comment: simple `ws.send("hola mundo");` envia el mensaje a tu websocket y lo que envies de tu servidor lo resiviras en `event.data` de tu funcion `ws.onmessage`

Comment: ok amigo gracias por tu respuesta pero la duda que tengo como lo recibo en otro html? que no sea desde el que lo envio?

Comment: todo es cuestion de condicinar tus envios y respuestas, tu veras la forma mas censilla de hacerlo, por token o simplemente por id de usuario.

Comment: Amigo, gracias por su ayuda pero sigo sin entender.